# How to get a Facebook access token on iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook, access-token

iOS beginner here. I have the following code:

```
[facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
NSString *string1=[facebook accessToken];
NSLog(string1);
```

The log shows: `miFOG1WS_7DL88g6d95Uxmzz7GCShsWx_FHuvZkmW0E.eyJpdiI6IjNZZkFBY1c5ZnBaMGEzOWM2RzNKbEEifQ.LNjl06lsOQCO9ArVARqff3Ur2XQHku3CMHDBKkpGg351EB33LGxVv96Hh5R860KDJL0cLq8QezSW0GovYxnhUucOwxlITV364sVKDXIzC3bAn9P_74r2Axl1SgOaTyMMkQ_aSQ2OWh-8d3Zn9BDt3pXVWzBLJ9I4XAosnw0GjuE`

This seems too long to be an access token. I read it's supposed to be only 40 characters long. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use delegate method:

```
- (void)fbDialogLogin:(NSString *)token expirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate
```

for more information you can refer to the following question :[Facebook Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151122/any-way-to-pull-out-session-key-from-access-token-returned-by-facebook-ios-sdk)

Comment: I'm not sure about the length there is no fixed one as you can see on that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408945/what-is-the-length-of-the-access-token-in-facebook-oauth2

Answer (score 121):

Using v3.2.1 as of March 20, 2013 of Facebook SDK.

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
```

If you prefer dot syntax,

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
```

For those using Swift;

```
var fbAccessToken = FBSession.activeSession().accessTokenData.accessToken
```

**Update for v4.1.0 SDK onwards**

*Objective-C*

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
```

*Swift*

```
var fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
```

Comment: Quick follow up question - would this token generated be the "long-term" access token described in their docs?  Thanks!

Comment: I believe all tokens obtained from native client is considered "long-term". The only time its "short-term" is probably for web clients. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: What is FBSession? Where do I access that?

Comment: Nevermind, I am using the new version of Facebook SDK.

Comment: @AndrewK I've updated the answer to reflect the updated SDK. Cheers!

Comment: For Swift the syntax is FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

Comment: For Swift 3, FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the Facebook SDK you can use the `FBSession` object to get and accessToken.
If the user authenticated to the app and you have an active session use:

```
NSString * accessToken = [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken];
```

to get the access token.

It worked for me.

Comment: The method suggested by abdus.me is deprecated in the 3.2 SDK. The proper way to access the accessToken is the one suggested by Nur Iman Izam: if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) { NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken]; ... }

Answer (score 4):

For SDK 4.0

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 1.2 and FB SDK 4.1:

```
var fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
```

Answer (score 3):

For FacebookLogin (0.9.0) Swift

```
import FacebookLogin

AccessToken.current?.tokenString
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)facebookClick:(id)sender {

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

     [login logOut];

    login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];


    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
             //   [login logOut];
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            // [login logOut];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             [self getUserInformation];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question not only for this person, but for readers in the future, who might not know why your code is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below for getting the access_token from ACAccountStore :

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType =  [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
NSDictionary *FBOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:FACEBOOK_APP_ID, ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:FBOptions completion:
 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
     if (granted) {

         NSArray *facebookAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
         FBAccount = [facebookAccounts firstObject];
         NSLog(@"token :%@",[[FBAccount credential] oauthToken]);

     } else {
         //Error
         NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",error);
         if([error code]== ACErrorAccountNotFound){
             NSLog(@"Account not found. Please setup your account in settings app"); 
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Account access denied");
         }

     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4 (2018)

```
FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who need to use swift with SDK 3.2.1:

```
let token = FBSession.activeSession().accessTokenData.accessToken
```