# Facebook token not having "|" as delimiter anymore? Cause of OAuth2?

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am developing an IM client for iPhone, which will have support for an FB account as well. I am using [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) for getting auth token.

But whatever token I fetch, it does not contain any "|" character as a delimiter. Isn't it supposed to be like `<app-id>|<session-id>|<digest>`? Thats what I have read. Now, there is no such delimiter. How do I go about fetching the session key now? Or is there any new method for XMPP communication?

Further, is this one of the changes in OAuth2? I see that it will be deprecated from Nov 5 (as of latest update), so the delimited string will not work after that? So that instead of using older authentication mechanism, I should be working on the new mechanism?

I would be really grateful if you could provide some documented evidence regarding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for here:
[Any way to pull out session key from access token returned by Facebook iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151122/any-way-to-pull-out-session-key-from-access-token-returned-by-facebook-ios-sdk)

So the point is that with Single-sign-on, we cant get a token that can be used for xmpp. So if you want to make a chat app, you must use the dialog method, and for that, make the changes as suggested in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

from where u get the said format?

the access token that you received is likely to be an encrypted token.  In your fb app settings, see if the option "OAuth migration" is enabled or not.  If it is enabled, then try to set it to disabled and see if this helps.